# Change the CSS on hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="counters2">
    <div class="one_fourth"> Item 1 <h4> 99$ </h4> </div>
    <div class="one_fourth last"> Item 2 <h4> 139$ </h4> </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS code:

```
.counters2 h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #999;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.counters2 .one_fourth {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #393939;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

How during a hover I can change the :

- Text color to white (#fff)
- Background color to green (#9eca45)

---

Problem with my actual code is the price between `<h4>` tags change color do not change to white until I make a hover on it. How can I changed that? What I tried:

```
.counters2 h4.active, .counters2 h4:hover {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.counters2 .one_fourth.active, .counters2 .one_fourth:hover {
    background-color: #9eca45;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `color` in `h4`, or to add a specific rule that override the `color: #999;`, like:

```
.counters2 .one_fourth:hover h4 {
    color: #fff;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/otjvfe9m/)